# draggable rows in a p:dataTable by handle

Tags: primefaces, datatable, drag-and-drop, row, draggable

I have a DataTable in which I added drag and drop support for the rows (draggableRows="true"). The problem is that wherever I click inside a row, I can drag it.

What I want is the possibility to drag the row only by a handle, the handle could be a column field with an icon at the left of the row for example (have a look at the screenshot), so if the user clicks on a row outside of the handle, there's no drag support; but if he clicks on the handle, he'll have the possibility to drag the entire row.

How could I implement this?

[image]

Comment: Can't you catch the ReorderEvent and then decide to perform the action depending the area clicked ? It's just a suggestion ...

Comment: @Ko2r: interesting idea! I'll try that :-)

Comment: You can look around this <p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{dtReorderView.onRowReorder}" update=":form:msgs" />

Comment: @Ko2r: I know that, and my listener is working fine with persistence and all that staff. I juste need a workarround for the handle probleme. Thanks

Comment: Just FYI since 6.2, PF has a built-in support for this. See my answer below for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/) is always with you. In there you can see [the makeRowsDraggable function on line 2727 in datatable.js](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L2727)

```
makeRowsDraggable: function() {
    var $this = this;

    this.tbody.sortable({
        placeholder: 'ui-datatable-rowordering ui-state-active',
        cursor: 'move',
        handle: 'td,span:not(.ui-c)',
        appendTo: document.body,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ui.helper.css('z-index', ++PrimeFaces.zindex);
        }, 
    ...
}
```

with a reference to the handle ('td, span:not(.ui-c)').

By overriding this function and having the handle point to a selector that explicitly refers to your handle, you can 'fix' it.

You can even make this generic by not assigning an explict string to the handle, but but looking it up on e.g. a custom pass-through attribute you define on the datatable where you put the 'string' in.

Did I mention already that [the source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/) is always with you? Good thing to remember when having further questions

Comment: It was positive! I overrided makeRowsDraggable() in a custom JS file and imported it in my main template, it worked like a charm. Thanks @Kukeltje

Comment: Great to hear. Remember, the source is always with you. Also in other cases

Comment: Just FYI since 6.2, PF has a built-in support for this. See my answer below for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Since Primefaces 6.2 p:datatable has a property `rowDragSelector` specifically for this purpose. See the example below:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.entities}" id="myTablePreferredId" rowDragSelector=".draggableHandle" draggableRows="true">

    <p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{myBean.onRowReorder}"/>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText styleClass="fa fa-arrows-v draggableHandle" />
    </p:column>

    ...

</p:dataTable>
```

For more details refer to the [primefaces documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datatable).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the same as the solution of @Kuketje.
Here is the source code (compatible with Primefaces 6.1)

```
if (PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable){
PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable = PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.extend({
    makeRowsDraggable: function () {
        var $this = this,
            draggableHandle = '.dnd-handle'; //change to what ever selector as you like

        this.tbody.sortable({
            placeholder: 'ui-datatable-rowordering ui-state-active',
            cursor: 'move',
            handle: draggableHandle,
            appendTo: document.body,
            start: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.css('z-index', ++PrimeFaces.zindex);
            },
            helper: function (event, ui) {
                var cells = ui.children(),
                    helper = $('<div class="ui-datatable ui-widget"><table><tbody></tbody></table></div>'),
                    helperRow = ui.clone(),
                    helperCells = helperRow.children();

                for (var i = 0; i < helperCells.length; i++) {
                    helperCells.eq(i).width(cells.eq(i).width());
                }

                helperRow.appendTo(helper.find('tbody'));

                return helper;
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var fromIndex = ui.item.data('ri'),
                    toIndex = $this.paginator ? $this.paginator.getFirst() + ui.item.index() : ui.item.index();

                $this.syncRowParity();

                var options = {
                    source: $this.id,
                    process: $this.id,
                    params: [
                        {name: $this.id + '_rowreorder', value: true},
                        {name: $this.id + '_fromIndex', value: fromIndex},
                        {name: $this.id + '_toIndex', value: toIndex},
                        {name: this.id + '_skipChildren', value: true}
                    ]
                }

                if ($this.hasBehavior('rowReorder')) {
                    $this.cfg.behaviors['rowReorder'].call($this, options);
                }
                else {
                    PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.handle(options);
                }
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if ($this.cfg.scrollable) {
                    PrimeFaces.scrollInView($this.scrollBody, ui.placeholder);
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

}

The solution from Vít Suchánek is not really working. It detects the drag&drop handle only when the page is ready. After the first drag&drop interaction, it is not going to work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to override Primefaces's setting of handler after initialization of UI sortable:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var sortableRows = $(".tableWithDraggableRows > tbody");
            if (sortableRows) {
                sortableRows.sortable("option", "handle", ".ui-icon-arrow-4");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle